# Sharepoint on submit function doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, forms, sharepoint, addeventlistener, preventdefault

I have a **working form** with a POST method that sends the values parsed in JSON to an external website. However it won't work if I host the form on Sharepoint.

I had to wrap the form  with a div because sharepoint didn't want to getElementsByClassName with only the form tag.

Now i'm stuck at the addEventListener Function for the submit button, which doesn't execute *handleFormSubmit*. The console shows no errors.

HTML (Shortened):

```
<div id="formAbc">
    <form class="content__form abc">
        <div class="abc__input-group">
            <label class="abc__label" for="iNumber">iNumber</label>
            <input class="infrastruktur__input infrastruktur__input--text" id="iNumber" name="iNumber" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="abc__input-group">
            <label class="abc__label" for="machineName">machineName</label>
            <input class="abc__input abc__input--text" id="machineName" name="machineName" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <button class="abc__button" type="submit">Absenden</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript: 
addEventListener:

```
const Formtest = document.getElementById('formAbc');
console.log(Formtest);
Formtest.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
```

handleFormSubmit:

```
const handleFormSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("default prevented");
 /// handling Data
};
```

Also tested wrapping all my javascript with

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
       //code
   }
}
```

Does Sharepoint accept handling things on 'submit', do I need to make an onclick() event on the button or do I have an error somewhere else?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `submit` handler directly to the form element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `<form>` tag, as Sharepoint doesn't allow these inside a CEWP. 
I solved this by using the `<fieldset>` tag instead and that solved all issues.

```
<fieldset>
 ....
</fieldset>
```

While you can use a costum tag as `<myform>`, this will break `form.elements` and it will not work.